# Wordpress use table sort functionality in own plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm creating a own plugin for wordpress where I have to view a set of data.

Now I want to use the wordpress default table view to display my data, and give some functionality to it.

default table:

[image: default table view]

Is there a way to use this table view for my own plugins (some classes or functions) or do I have to create something similar by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built "WordPress table view" function. I know someone who uses this same layout in one of his plugins and he simply copied the source code and than made edits where necessary for generating the tables cells etc..

Comment: hm. it would be great if we could use such things like this table, validation and other things for our own plugins. i'll take a look at some source codes.

Comment: I definitely agree with you, but hijacking the source code on this one shouldn't be too hard. You could really make a straight up copy and than use simple loop for the table cells.

Comment: yeah, hijacked the table now ;) if nobody has a better solution i'll accept your answer.

Comment: Sounds good. Honestly this is a pretty decent and useable plugin idea, but a straight copy and paste with a simple loop is an easy solution. Post a screen of how it comes out!

Comment: first quick try looks something like this: http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/6357394/Bild%202.png

Comment: That looks great for a "first, quick try" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a WordPress class (WP_List_Table) as part of the API to achieve these tables documented at http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table

You need to extend the class to provide your own data and although not well documented at that URL you can also use views to filter the data (as used in the comment admin page to show All, Pending, approved, Spam and Trash).

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple tut with Example plugin try this one, it uses jquery datatable.

http://kvcodes.com/2014/02/sortable-data-table-wordpress-frontback-end/

and if you want it on your front end try this,

http://kvcodes.com/2014/02/sortable-data-table-wordpress-frontback-end/

hope this will help you.

Comment: Both urls are the same!